# Parameterized SPARQL string

Tags: sparql

I'm developing my own SPARQL parameterized query String. I want to inject values into the string using a specified convention.

I'm using a colon followed by a number to denote injectable values, e.g.,
`Filter(?myVar = :1)`. Then I would search for ":" followed by a number and replace it. Only one restriction: no ttl based uris are allowed, so that the ":" won't mix with uris.

Apache Jena uses variables for injection (normal SPARQL variables that start with a question mark followed by a variable identifier) and dot net Rdf uses "@" followed by identifier.

**Question**
Do you see anything wrong with my approach of ":" followed by number? What should be considered to provide a method with minimal ambiguity or undesired behaviours?

Comment: isn't a standard SPARQL parser trying to parse this as a prefixed URI then? I mean, ok if you adapt the parser to prevent parse errors, ok - anyways, it's not clear what exactly you are implementing where? which SPARQL API? Just Jena and DotNetRDF? And then you want to modify the query string by injecting values before it is being parsed?

Comment: I am developing my own parameterized query String. Dot net and Jena were just examples how others do it. I am seeking recommendations of possible ambiguities or challenges that could be caused by using my aforementioned convention.

Comment: And yes. Parsing is done in runtime when the place holders have been already replaced.